# Redirection using NodeJS and Post action from python code

Tags: html, node.js, redirect

After testing some answer from stackoverflow, I am at the same point. I can't redirect to home page (localhost).

What I want : post an action from python code (it works):

```
import requests
SIGNUP_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/home'
resp = requests.post(SIGNUP_URL)
```

I want this request open my home page via nodejs (express/http). My nodejs code :

```
app.post('/home', function(req, res){    
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
    console.log('redirected to home page')
});
```

I tried using the full http adress, also with statuscode, also tries with res.writeHead... also with another http adress..
Nodejs received correctly the Post because the console.log write "redirected to home page", but no redirection...
If anyone have another solution to play ?
Thanks.

NodeJs Full code (almost) :

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
const path = require('path');
const formidable = require('formidable');       // pas comprendre
const {execFile, exec, spawn} = require ('child_process');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));   


app.post('/kill', function(req, res){            
    exec(__dirname + '/public/kill.py');                 
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
    console.log('script killed')
});

app.post('/timer', function(req, res){                  
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/status.html');
    var info = req.body;
    io.emit('messageFromServer', info);
    console.log(info)
});

app.post('/home', function(req, res){    
    response.writeHead(301, {
        'Location': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.html'
    });
    response.end();
    console.log('redirected to home page')
});


server.listen(8000, console.log("listening to port 8000"));
```

Comment: please add full code of your nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve html file use below

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

// viewed at http://localhost:8080
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(8080);
```

and If you want to redirect use below

```
response.writeHead(301, {
  Location: <redirect-ur>
});
response.end();
```

Comment: Thanks, I test the redirect use, and that write " ReferenceError: response is not defined " is response a module ?

Comment: Hi, when I post  /home from my python code, I want the nodejs redirect the actual page open to the home page (http://localhost:8000). Is it possible with nodejs ?

Comment: Hi I change response to res (in order to remove "referenceError", but when I test, no changes, the html page stay the same.

Comment: While this solution doesn't work (for me) I use another solution : transfer a link from python code to nodejs and write this link into my html page...

Answer (score 0):

I try both solutions :

```
app.post('/home', function(req, res){    

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
    });

    res.writeHead(301, {
        Location: 'http://localhost:8000/index.html'
    });
    res.end();
    console.log('redirected to home page')
});
```

And nothing appears...
No error message, no change, nothing. I think this method doesn't work.